# some questions about CRS collision in LTE

Tags: lte

In the case of CRS collision in LTE, is the serving cell and the neighbouring cell always PRB aligned? For example, if they are PRB aligned, port0 will always collide with port0, otherwise port0 will possibly collide with port1. The details of CRS collision is specified in which specifications?

Comment: Welcome. (1) Please define "CRS collision" and "PRB aligned".  (2) The answer to the 2nd question is no. Why do you think that it should be? (3) What issues?

Comment: Are you referring to the DSS between NR and LTE?

Comment: It's within the LTE scope. When CRSs of the serving cell and the neighbouring cell occupy the same time and frequency resource, they collide. If the two cells are PRB aligned, then port0 always collides with port 0. If not, port 0 possibly collides with port 1.

Comment: This may be a new feature. To the best of my knowledge, (1) this kind of collision is avoided by network planning that adjacent cells have different CRS patterns and (2) two cells are always PRB aligned (by your definition, I don't know anything in LTE that makes port 0 of one cell overlap with other ports of other cells. Could you please cite the source that proposes such idea? Thanks).

Comment: Please see page 8 of https://www.qualcomm.com/content/dam/qcomm-martech/dm-assets/documents/Research_LTE_Heterogeneous_Networks.v2.20110201.pdf. And could you please cite the source proving that two cells are always PRB aligned?

Comment: Ok you are talking about LTE HetNet. My statements are all about macro cell deployment.  I am not a HetNet expert and I could be wrong, but I don't see anything on page 8 of Qualcomm's document that suggests the idea of PRB misalignment.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see how this can help as the collision is still there as port 0 still collides with port 1 (instead of the another port 0). You can check figure 2 of [this patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e0/5e/a8/65a3ff85f61ff7/WO2018064121A1.pdf) and see that in general, we avoid CRS collision by choosing suitable cell ID.

Comment: In the case that CRS collision cannot be avoided, interference cancellation is used. Check this paper for the idea https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315977625_A_PCI_planning_algorithm_for_jointly_reducing_reference_signal_collisions_in_LTE_uplink_and_downlink.

And no, I don't know anything in LTE that suggest we change the PRB alignment for interference management purpose.

Comment: It doesn't help to reduce interference. But it may help reduce the possibilities to be handled.

Comment: I don't see how and I know nowhere in 3GPP standards that talks about the idea.